# wp8.x and windows 8 timer issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a simple quiz app, where I am showing time elapsed with combination or timer and stop watch. But timer is not reliable, it stop updating after couple of seconds or update slow with lag in time.

```
private void StartChallenge()
    {
        LoadQuestion();
        System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(updateTime), null, 0, 1000); //start timer immediately and keep updating it after a second
        stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
    }

    private async void updateTime(object state)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => txtTimeElapsed.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00} elapsed", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with above code. But I don't see timer working reliably in app.

Anyone faced similar problem. Is any other timer I can use for UI.

Thanks

Comment: Try to save this.Dispatcher.RunAsync() into local variable, await that variable and check if task has something in Exception property.

Comment: The Timer is getting garbage collected.  You'll need to store a reference to it in a field of your class, the local variable is not good enough.

Comment: So you mean to say Timer t should be a class variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the UI in Windows Runtime you should use `DispatcherTimer` - it ticks on the UI thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx

```
Stopwatch sw;
DispatcherTimer timer;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    sw = new Stopwatch();
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sw.Start();

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += (i, j) => { txtBlock.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString(); };
    timer.Start();    
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is solution, I'll give it a day of testing and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It would update timer at interval of One Second and also Update the `TimerTextBlock`

```
public void LoadTimer()
{
    int sec = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer((obj) =>
    {
        Dispatcher pageDispatcher = obj as Dispatcher;

        pageDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            sec++;
            TimerTextBlock.Text = sec.ToString();
        });

    }, this.Dispatcher, 1000, 1000);
}
```